# Interaction between high ground, detection, and "vision"

Tags: starcraft-2

After getting nuked several times in a row last night, I came up with a somewhat esoteric question.

Let's say I have a spore crawler in my base.  If a cloaked unit comes within range of the crawler, it is revealed, and my hydralisks can kill the ghost.  That's easy.

Now let's say my hatchery is on low ground, and there is high ground right near it.  I build a spore crawler right at the base of the high ground.  If a ghost is up on that high ground, cloaked or not, i can't see him because I don't have vision of the high ground.  Still pretty easy.

Now I move an overlord (not overseer) over to where the ghost is.  Now I can see the ghost if it is uncloaked. If there was a hydralisk at the bottom of the cliff, it could attack the ghost because the overlord's vision allows the hydra to target the ghost.

Now for the tricky part.  What if the ghost is cloaked?  Does the overlord's vision allow the spore crawler's detection ability to "target" the ghost and reveal it, the same way the hydra could target it in the previous scenario?  Or would I need to build a spore crawler on the high ground?

(I know I could also morph an overseer, but that is not relevant to this question, which is focused on the exact mechanics of detection and how it interacts with vision of high ground.)

Comment: Now that is one darn good question!

Comment: Heh.  I am nothing if not curious.  And as an engineer I can't help wondering about the precise rules behind what happens in games.  And in this case, my question actually has some practical value, however small :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes.

Here's the picture proof:[image]

Comment: Used a dark templar instead of a cloaked ghost, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Wow, that's very different from how I thought it would work. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: You are playing as protoss in that picture..

Comment: False. I am playing as Red. I just used the staredit default, which gave me the protoss menu theme. However, the red ring around the dark templar would be green were it my unit, and the command card would likewise be filled with move, attack, stop, hold position, etc.

Comment: @BlueRaja when you create a custom map you set what your race is, but you can add units from any race.

Comment: I gotta start using the map editor it looks like, so i can start to answer my own questions.  thanks for a perfect demo.

Comment: also, this is good news for my future drones.  no more nuke deaths.  or at least a few less.

Answer (score 8):

I'd have to double check to be sure, but here is what I believe to be the case.

Here is how vision works in Starcraft 2: All units share vision.  What one sees any can see.

Here is how detection works in Starcraft 2: All units with in detection radius from a detector and within vision are detected.

Thus your Spore Crawler provides detection radius and your overseer provides vision, thus a Hydralisk (or any other unit that would normally be capable of attacking the ghost) can.

Comment: good way to summarize the mechanics. i knew the first rule, but the second was what i was unsure about.

Comment: @Peter I feel knowing the mechanics is more important than knowing the answer as I can derive one from the other but not necessarily the other way around

Comment: also, to be perfectly nitpicky, it is a spore crawler, not a spine crawler.  sadly spine crawlers can't detect.  I don't have enough rep yet to fix it for you.

Comment: i am always much happier to know the mechanics rather than specific answers.  though it can be fun to try to figure out the mechanics, given a certain set of data.

Comment: @Peter Agreed.  Sadly I wasn't at home where I could take a nice screenshot like Raven.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the detection will work.